# How to add folders structure in VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In older versions of VS when you dragged a folder from windows file explorer into your VS solution, it would make a reference to that folder including all the sub folders' structure and files.
In VS2015 when I drag a folder into the solution it simpley makes a reference to all the files in that folder and sub folder but ignore the folder structure.
So it dumps all the files reference under one filter.

Is there a way to get the former behavior in VS2015?

Comment: I don't use VS 2015, but in older version of VS, you can add folder structure in your project. Right click on your project and choose Add | New Folder. If you want to add a sub folder, right click on your folder and do the same.

Comment: My issue is with adding reference to existing folders, not creating new folders. I usually add my framework folder as reference and then remove all the sub folders that are not relevant to my current project. I cannot do this with VS2015

Answer (score 4):

The way that I do this is to add the folders to the project structure (i.e. underneath the .sln file) and then enable "Show All Files" (you may need a "Refresh").

Right click the folders you want to add and click "Include In Project".

(I didn't know about the drag and drop!)

Comment: I saw this answer elsewhere, the issue is that I want a reference, not to make a copy of them inside the project. It's a framework several projects use, it won't be smart to maintain a copy of the framework for every project that use it

Comment: I'd really love to do this, but when I right click on a folder or a file there is no option to "Include in Project" - it is getting very tedious to include a 100 or so files by adding an existing file one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follows:

the reason you don't see the "include in project" is :  either you created the solution externally to visual studio community or the solution got corrupt

to resolve this:

1. make a backup the solution (just in case)
2. in solution explorer - right click the project name , and choose "Rebuil solution"
3. Press the "show all files" (if not pressed already)
4. go to the folder you want to include, and now you should see the "include in project" option. Choose it
5. press again the "show all files" button (on top of the "solution explorer") to once again hide irrelevant files/folders from your solution explorer

Answer (score 0):

Working with VS2015 and SSIS Solution:
Miscellaneous Folder - When I created a Sub-Folder in VS2015 and then Added the files contained therein it added them but not with the Name I Had but the name "Miscellaneous".  Not how it worked in previous versions!

I was able to Add a Custom-Named Folder to the Solution but not the Project.  When adding existing files to the Project it put them under the aforementioned Miscellaneous Folder.